# Call to member function setDate() on string

Tags: php, datetime, time

I am trying to replace the current day with the last day of the month but the error returns

> Call to member function setDate() on string

on the last line. Everything is working correctly except for the setDate function

```
//current date which is 2017-08-28 10:50:30 
 $string = $date1; 
 $dateM = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", $string);
//getting the day of the month which is 28
 $dateMonth = $dateM->format("d");
 //if the day is 28
 if($dateMonth >= 28){
    //change the day to 31
    $dateMonth = 31;
    //current date which is 28/08/2017
    $out = $date1;
    //replace 28 with 31
    $date1 = $out->setDate($out->format('Y'), $out->format('m'), $dateMonth , $out->format('H'), $out->format('i'), $out->format('s'));
 }
```

Comment: what is `$date1` ?

Comment: It appears that $date1 is a string and not a date literal. Try using $dateM.

Comment: Second last line, ``$out->setDate`` - out is a string and therefore doesn't have a ``setDate`` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `t` in format specifier on `DateTime`'s `format` function.

[date format specifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#refsect1-function.date-parameters)

> **format character**: t
>
> **Description**: Number of days in the given month
>
> **Example returned values**: 28 through 31

```
<?php
$input = '2017-08-28 10:50:30';

$date_time = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $input);
$last_day_of_month = $date_time->format('Y-m-t H:i:s');

echo $last_day_of_month;
```

This gives:

```
2017-08-31 10:50:30
```

Demo: https://eval.in/844314

Answer (score 0):

The error message says, that `$out` is `String` not `DateTime` object. So you something mixed up.

Maybe should be `$out = $dateM;` instead of `$out = $date1;`?

Comment: ya I have noticed that, it was my bad

Answer (score 0):

Setting `$dateMonth` to `31` might not be a good idea as come months have 30 days in. PHPs [data function](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) allows you to use `t` as a format, which gives you the number of days in the given month. So you could use that to get the last day of the current month:

`date("Y-m-t")`